# Passing javascript variable through url and decoding to a php variable

Tags: php, javascript, json, iframe

I found this little script to allow users to embed a simple javascript code on their site to show an iframe from my site.  This works perfectly, however I am trying to pass 1 variable through the code they embed and on my end set it as a php variable.

I apologize in advance I dont know very much about javascript! sorry.

Sample code a user would embed (widget type code)

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.mysite.com/public/iframe.js" rel='{"id":"1"}'></script>
```

And this is the code that generates the iframe on my end

```
// Set path to the iframe file
var filePath = 'http://www.mysite.com/public/iframe.php';
// Setup the iframe target
var iframe='<iframe id="frame" name="widget" src ="#" width="100%" height="1"   
marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe>';
// Write the iframe to the page
document.write(iframe);

var myIframe = parent.document.getElementById("frame");
// Setup the width and height
myIframe.height = 350;
myIframe.width = 960;

myIframe.src = filePath;
// set the style of the iframe
myIframe.style.border = "1px solid #999";
myIframe.style.padding = "8px";
```

The end goal is to the rel attribute id = 1 and assign it to a php variable for further use.  I did a lot of looking around, it seems that json_decode is the answer but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the `id` as a `rel` attribute, just add it to the url directly:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.mysite.com/public/iframe.js?id=1"></script>
```

Then access it in your php.

```
$id = (array_key_exists('id', $_GET)) ? $_GET['id'] : null;
```

This is a shorthand `if`, which checks to make sure the id has been added to the url. It's the same as:

```
if(array_key_exists('id', $_GET) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
} else {
    $id = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the rel attribute is not something used in an iframe tag.  That is usually used in an  tag with rel="nofollow" so that search engines don't follow that link.

I haven't tried this but maybe you can just send that parameters over after a question mark in your embed code.  Like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.mysite.com/public/iframe.js?id=1"></script>
```

Then your PHP code just looks for that in a GET request.

```
<?php
echo $_REQUEST['id'];
?>
```

Of course this assumes that your receiving script is written in PHP.  Since you show a .js extension I'm not sure the PHP code is executing?  Also, I'm not 100% sure you can pass parameters like this in a javascript embed.

Comment: You can use rel on an iframe, although I'm not sure why you would - it's often used on various tags for microformats. And you can pass a param in the url like that. But I beat you to it :D

Comment: i tried passing it like you guys said in the url itself but it doesnt work.  I am assuming the issue is the embed code calls a javascript file that calls a php file which is the file that needs the variable, not really the .js file.

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript you add this to find the script tag itself:

```
var allScripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
currentScript = allScripts[allScripts.length - 1 ];
```

Then, it's up to you to either use `rel` attribute value or decoding the `src` attribute.

*Btw, this may not always work when script elements are added in an asynchronous manner, in which case you have to check that `src` matches your filename or check for the `rel` perhaps*